# The keyboard pushes a div up & out of the screen

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 to make a website which will be part of another native app in a webview so I don't user cordova or any native plugins.
I have a form with an embedded Google Map View above the elements and here is my HTML :

```
<div  style="height: 40%; width: 100%">
  <div id="map_loader" *ngIf="showMapLoader">
    <div class="sk-wave">
      <div class="sk-rect sk-rect1"></div>
      <div class="sk-rect sk-rect2"></div>
      <div class="sk-rect sk-rect3"></div>
      <div class="sk-rect sk-rect4"></div>
      <div class="sk-rect sk-rect5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div #mapCanvas style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" padding>
  <ion-list>
......
......
.....
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

and here is my CSS :

```
  #map_loader {
    margin:auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .scroll-content {
    top: 38%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 32px;
  }
```

Now once the user open the website on his phone and start filling the form the keyboard shifts the map out of the screen ( Up ) and it stays that way and a blank empty space shows bellow the form.

Am I doing it right? Is that happening because of my CSS? and what is the best way to make a div takes a specific percentage of the screen height? I tried `ion-grid` but it seems that it can't help me for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's bug in ionic, once you focus on any input the keyboard will show up and will add `padding-bottom` for the `scroll-content` class to lift the for above the keyboard and it doesn't remove the `padding-bottom` after you close the keyboard.
I tried to check if I have any JS event on the mobile keyboard but we don't so my work around is to set a fixed `padding-bottom` for the `scroll-content` class to prevent changing it on the runtime.

```
.scroll-content {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Change in the AndroidManifest.xml file did the trick for me. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: Thank you so so much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can avoid this issue by using [**Ionic grid**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/).You need to set `CSS` as shown below.

*your-page.scss*

```
  ion-grid {
      min-height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: so I have to put everything in an `ion-grid`? like a container?

Comment: Yes, You need to do that way.