# Ionic 3 - Keyboard pushes content up, and over other content, with no reason

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on a simple app in Ionic.

I have a problem that the keyboard pushes my input field up and over another div while there is enough space for they keyboard. How do I fix this? I already looked around on the internet but wasn't able to find any solution to my problem.

This is what happens:

[image: App]

As you can see, the text is in the image and there is no reason for it being so high. There is more then enough space below it.

**This is my code:**

HTML:

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding class="login content">

  <div class="logo-container">
      <img src="assets/imgs/Mikos_logo.jpeg" class="logo-img">
  </div>

  <div class="center">
      <p>Vul hier je naam in:</p>
      <ion-item class="code-field">
          <ion-input placeholder="naam" type="text" (keyup)="nameInput()" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>      
  </div>



</ion-content>
```

CSS:

```scss
page-login {

    .login {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .logo-container{
        position: absolute;
        width: 400px;
        left: calc(50% - 400px / 2);
      }

      .logo-img{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }

    .center{
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        width: 300px;
        left: calc(50% - 300px / 2);
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */

        .logo-container{
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            left: calc(50% - 300px / 2);
        }
    }

}
```

**What I have tried:**

I have added the [Ionic native keyboard](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/) and added this in my app module:

```ts
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false } ),
```

This unfortunately did not work.

**Update:**

Adding

```css
.scroll-content {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

is also not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug of Ionic 3 and can be fixed by adding the following CSS style:

```css
.scroll-content {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

I have had similar issues and this piece of CSS fixed it.

When an input is focused, Ionic adds some padding to the bottom of the `scroll-content` class, to create room for the keyboard.

---

**Update**

Relative top positioning may cause the issue (as well).

Answer (score 0):

This person's answer helped me"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61337530/10661436

Basically just go to your AndroidManifest.xml file,
search for:

 `android:windowSoftInputMode=ABC`

Replace "ABC" with `adjustPan`

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your config.xml and make sure you have your keyboard plugin installed.

```
<preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="ionic" />
```